# How to make order by faster?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table with several columns to order by. Those columns are **float values with their corresponding indexes** on them. The table has **around 5 million rows**.

The table structure id something like that:

```
MyTable(id,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
MyWords(id,word)
TableWords(wordID,MyTableID)
```

I need to run this query in a faster way which is basically a 100 top. I would like to have some suggestions on how to do that better:

```
select sql_no_cache a.* 
from MyWords w
left join TableWords wl on w.id = wl.wordID
left join MyTable a on wl.MyTableID = a.id
where w.word = 'WordToSearch'
order by a.a desc
limit 100
```

**The indexes:**

```
ALTER TABLE `a` ADD INDEX `a` (`a`);
ALTER TABLE `a` ADD INDEX `b` (`b`);
```

**Using explain:**

```
1   SIMPLE  w   const   uniqueWord,fulltext_word    uniqueWord  63  const   1   Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  wl  ref wordID  wordID  4   const   5597    
1   SIMPLE  a   eq_ref  PRIMARY,id  id  4   test.wl.a   1
```

**Describe TableWords:**

```
MyTableID   int(11)   NO    MUL
wordID      int(11)   NO    MUL
```

**Describe MyWords:**

```
id      int(11)     NO  PRI     auto_increment
word    varchar(20) YES UNI
```

**Describe MyTable:**

```
id  int(11) NO  PRI auto_increment
a   float   YES MUL 
b   float   YES MUL
```

I can order by my table and it is fast, but in the moment I make a left join to that table it doesnt use the indexes anymore. I put more data in my question.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the actual schema and indexes? It's fine if you change the column names, but this isn't enough detail. Also an `explain` on your query would help.

Comment: @Schwern I updated my question with more data.

Comment: It seems to be ordering a temporary table, is that it?

Comment: It's important to know if `TableWords.wordID` and `TableWords.MyTableID` are declared as foreign keys, which automatically indexes them. Simplest thing is to show us the actual schemas and indexes for all tables, again you can change the column names if you like. `describe <tablename>` and `show indexes for <tablename>` will do.

Comment: @Schwern I forgot to tell its a MyISAM table. I put the "describe TableWords" data in the question.

Comment: All of them, please, and their indexes. Doing it piecemeal is just slowing things down. And it's inadvisable to use MyISAM without a good reason.

Comment: @Schwern I do have MyISAM for good reasons, anyway this will change soon but is a huge change as big is the database.

Comment: There are no good reasons anymore to use MyISAM. It was an excellent engine for its day, but that's over now.

Comment: @Mjh Unless you have an old MySQL version with Binary Logs that needs FULLTEXT index with huge data to migrate to the new InnoDB server. It takes time guys thats not the point of my question... and yes, of course I know exactly how awful is MyISAM and the security issues with my current MySQL version, but thats a different problem...

Comment: To further pinpoint the exact cause of your issue (I'm quite sure your query scans the whole 5m data set and does it on disk), you can use profiling. Executing the following will let you know which parts of the whole process take the most time: `SET PROFILING = 1; SELECT ... (your query here); SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;` (of course, turn profiling off afterwards). At that point, you can see what causes the processing to be slow. My guess would be that it's because of extremely slow HDD.

Comment: @Mjh very helpful, thanks a million

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: Remove `LEFT`; see what changes.

Comment: Switch to InnoDB.  There are essentially no "good reasons" for MyISAM any more.  And MyISAM is going away in the next release.

Comment: Different indexing and optimization options exist in InnoDB.

Comment: What is "a 100 top"?

Comment: Which table has 5M rows?  How big are the other tables?  How many rows would you get with the `LIMIT 100`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a lot more information if you are looking for specific optimizations. However in a general sense here is some things you can look into. I'll provide a short list with a link to the full details.

1. Use Indexes
2. Modify/Update *filesort* algorithm
3. Make sure columns use only the smallest amount of space required
4. Have lots of space available in the temporary directory

**Optimize Order By:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

**Optimize Limit:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: This is too generic man. I can order by my table and it is fast, but in the moment I make a left join to that table it doesnt use the indexes anymore. I put more data in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to speed it up is to have `word` and `a` in the same table *and* have `INDEX(word, a)`.

By doing that, *both* the filtering (`WHERE word = '...'`) and the ordering can be done in an index.  That allows `LIMIT 100` to simply peel off the first hundred rows -- instead of collecting all the filtered rows, sorting them, and only then being able to peel off 100.

There is another requirement:  'WordToSearch' must map to only one `a.id`.  It is unclear from your description whether the joins are 1:1 or 1:many or many:many.